# Cannot force Tensorflow 2.10 and Keras to work in Notebook with GTX 1660Ti [Solved]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

To start with.
Python v: 3.10.6
Tensorflow v: 2.10.1
Cuda v: 12.0
Cudnn: 8.1
gpu: GTX 1660Ti (supports cuda)

I'm fighting with this problem for almost 2 days now. I cannot force TF to run image recognition training model (ktrain) on gpu inside jupyter notebook.

That's the start of the file

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

the output as follows

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
Num GPUs Available:  1
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 9175052246053814955
xla_global_id: -1
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 4163895296
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 3853720177835357027
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
xla_global_id: 416903419
]
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

here I also found this solution but didn't work either.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
import pandas as pd
import ktrain as kt
from ktrain import vision as vis
```

everything should be working just fine however when I try to run the training (even with ensurance of using gpu)

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'): learner.autofit(1e-4)
```

my cpu usage skyrockets but the gpu isn't used.

Here's the model set up part of the code but i don't think it matters.

```
model = vis.image_classifier('pretrained_resnet50', train_data, val_data)
learner = kt.get_learner(model=model, train_data=train_data, val_data=val_data, 
                         workers=4, use_multiprocessing=False, batch_size=16)
```

I'm pulling my hair and no matter the lengths I go, I cannot force the gpu to be used. I tried with older versions of TF and python and still no results. I haven't tried it outside the jupyter notebook but I don't think that'd the case.

edit1:
[CPU usage and allocated memory, no GPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCQF3.png)

edi2:
[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1aW1.png)

edit3 solve:
I guess I've been using GPU all the time I just expected better results that's why I thought that the GPU isn't used.

Solution:
if you're running `nvidia-smi` in the cmd while running your learning and the GPU memory is (almost) full, GPU is used in training.

Comment: How exactly are you determining the GPU usage?

Comment: By checking in a task manager. It’s always cpu which goes to around 70%

Comment: It looks like TF recognizes the GPU, you should be checking if it is allocating some memory.

Comment: I added the image in edit how my task manager looks like.

Comment: CPU usage does not tell you anything, have you checked GPU use with nvidia-smi?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I also meant GPU memory.

Comment: Just checked, gpu isn't allocated any memory although TF should have employed all of free memory. screen in edit2.

Comment: I reinstalled literally everything and I set up everything from 0 and now when I run nvidia-smi it shows that the GPU memory is allocated. I guess everything was working from the start because I still get the same results but now I'm sure that GPU is used because when I run it on CPU it was taking 10x more time to train. I guess I just expected better results that's why I thought that GPU isn't employed by TF. Thank You all for help, I really learnt a lot in the process of troubleshooting it.